# Error while installing Tensorflow and other applications

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a project and have to install the following apps:
tensorflow
keras
imutils
numpy
opencv-python
matplotlib
scipy

But it is showing error?

what to do.
Tried restarting and all, but to no use. Please check
It is for a face mask detection tool project for me
Here's the thing

Code posted as SS as i dont know how to use this stack overflow lol
[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvjTL.jpg)  [Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef8PN.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please see how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the errors and code as text, not images. Also please post the content of your `requirements.txt`. Where did you get that file?

Comment: Contents: tensorflow>=1.15.2keras==2.3.1
imutils==0.5.3
numpy==1.18.2
opencv-python==4.2.0.*
matplotlib==3.2.1
scipy==1.4.1
 got it from a youtuber

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you what to do. Also do not post text as images.

Comment: yes but i cant quite figure out what to do. i have installed visual c++ but still nothing happened. i dont know what to post a code as i am new and the website is showing errors all day.